# decreasing the width of bar graph in matlab

Tags: matlab

I wrote the code below to make a bar graph but the problem is that the width of the bar is very big and i need to make the width thinner, when i change it from the fig properties the whole graph become smaller .. any help?

[image: original photo]

[image: after modifying the width and the whole graph become smaller which i don't need that to happen]

```
x = [2,3,4,5,6];
y = [80.32,95.2,92.6,75.6,65.7]
figure;
bar(x,y,'b');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a third input argument to `bar` which specifies width:

```
bar(x,y,.4,'b'); %// change ".4" as needed
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, what shall i do to change the color from blue to gray?

Comment: Normally I wouldn't comment but, due to the issues that can arise with transparency, setting the `'FaceColor'` property is a more direct and stable way to do this: `h=bar(x,y,.4,'FaceColor',[0.5,0.5,0.5])`

Comment: @RTL You are right. It's better to set the `'FaceColor'` directly as you say